# tf-idf string similarity function for postgresql

Tags: string, postgresql, similarity, tf-idf, fuzzy-search

Can you help me to construct or find a plpgsql string similarity function based on tf-idf, corpus-wide?
I am aware of the smlar extension, but I have certain reasons why not to use smlar. Is there any other available package, function or suggested approach?
Also, no python code, it must be pure plpgsql function.

Thanks.

Comment: For more detailed information about similarity strings on PostgreSQL, please visit this URL:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/pgtrgm.html

Comment: @RaminFaracov thank you, I am aware of the pgtrgm extension and I am already using it. However, I need TF-IDF or Soft TF-IDF string matching similarity metrics, taking care of relative importance of words in a corpus.

Comment: @RaminFaracov pgtrgm can only work in English.